# Ubuntu 9.10 screen on VirtualBox turns black?

Tags: virtualbox

Hi guys I have win7 and I wanted to move to Ubuntu,I got a Ubuntu 9.10 desktop edition DVD and installed it on VirtualBox, but I had a problem with the screen display size. I followed the tutorial here: [VirtualBox/Ubuntu 9.10: Changing Screen Resolution](http://www.mikesouthby.co.uk/2009/11/virtualboxubuntu-9-10-changing-screen-resolution/).

I restarted Ubuntu; it starts good, but the desktop won't show up. It turns black and nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think you'll find that  this question gets marked as Off Topic. Mainly because the version of Ubuntu (9.10) is not supported any more,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: Then please close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a good internet connection, download the Ubuntu 12.04LTS for the most stable release of Ubuntu, and the currently most supported version.  You will probably enjoy it much better than 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

without beeing able to exactly point out what went wrong on ur virtualbox install, i think it make sense to suggest u two relevant things:

1. u really should use a more actual version of ubuntu then 9.10! besides that the newer version may better support new hardware, i fear 9.10 isnt even supported with updates anymore.so i suggest u to use 12.04 which is a LTS (long time support) version.
2. if u wanna give ubuntu a try,u also can boot a fresh ubuntu live-system from DVD or USB and play around with it without changing anything to the actual configuration of ur machine.

and to ur question, it may a bit unprecise but i would suggest u to also try the virtualbox install with a fresher ubuntu like 12.04 + to make sure it matches ur hardware better.

have fun (-: